# How to get the response of form with POST method by cURL?

Tags: php, html, parsing, post, curl

Sorry for my English.
I need to get a price on [this page](http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx?pid=000000000501204050) with php and curl. 
This page use HTML form with POST method to get product content.

I tried to get an answer in this way:

```
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Curl\Curl;

$curl = new Curl();

$curl->post('http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx?pid=000000000501204050');
// or 
$curl->post('http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx', array(
    'pid' => '000000000501204050',
));

echo $curl->response;
```

I used https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! However, this is not a place where we do your job – it is not entirely clear what you are asking and, most importantly, what have you tried? Show us how far you've got, your code, your research.

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited the question.

Comment: php-curl-class is new to me (but i'm a bit familiar with the original curl, http://curl.haxx.se/). Anyway, i looked up the documentation at https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class, for $curl->post and noticed that it could also be used in this way too:  $curl->post('http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx', array(
    'pid' => '000000000501204050'
));

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the page you tried to request in your code. In my browser, it showed me the price just fine. So I tried the `curl` terminal command, and, sure enough, it said 'Moved Permanently'.

The site simply requires you to have a (session) cookie to visit, so under normal circumstances, your browser is first served the 'Moved Permanently' alongside with the session cookie. It is then automatically redirected wherever, where it is served the proper product page, because it already has the cookie. (This may involve multiple redirects.)

Looking at it in more detail now, I can see that the only cookie required is 'StoreDetails'.

I don't know how this cookie is generated, but here is mine:

```
StoreDetails={5F28ADB5-0BD9-476F-9643-B01AEBB4319A}
```

So, adding this to your code should help:

```php
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Curl\Curl;

$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setCookie('StoreDetails', '{5F28ADB5-0BD9-476F-9643-B01AEBB4319A}');
$curl->post('http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx?pid=000000000501204050');
echo $curl->response;
```